# Jquery .scrollTop() and .scrollLeft() on $(document).ready() not working

Tags: jquery, window, scrolltop, ready

I'm having a problem with scrollTop() and scrollLeft() on $(document).ready()
I want to to move to centre square on load. I wrote this code, but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            cur_window_height = $(window).height();
            cur_window_width = $(window).width();
            full_width = cur_window_width * 3;
            full_height = cur_window_height * 3;

            $('body').css({ 'width': full_width, 'heigth': full_height });
            $('#view_table').css({ 'width': full_width, 'height': full_height });

            $('#cur').scrollTop(cur_window_height);
            $('#cur').scrollLeft(cur_window_width);

        });

    </script>
    <style>
        #current_active {
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

        #view_table {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1px" id="view_table">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="cur">here is center</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This code not working. What I did wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First up, `heigth` should be `height` in the `$('body')` line.

Comment: it's not a problem. but i changes it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/JX2Pu/)

you can set `html`, `body`, `table` with CSS % width and heights

then as @PalashMondal pointed out set `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` on the `html`/`body` elements

```
|<html> 100% W&H ------------|
|<body> 300% W&H -------------------------------------------------------------|
|<table id="view_table"> 100% W&H---------------------------------------------|
| cell 1/3 W&H               | cell  1/3 W&H          | cell  1/3 W&H         |
|----------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
| cell 1/3 W&H               | cell  1/3 W&H          | cell  1/3 W&H         |
|----------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
| cell 1/3 W&H               | cell  1/3 W&H          | cell  1/3 W&H         |
|----------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------|
```

```
html, body, #view_table {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, #view_table {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width:300%;
    height:300%;
}
#view_table td {
    width:33.333%;
    height:33.333%;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cur_window_height = $(window).height();
    cur_window_width = $(window).width();

    $('html, body').scrollTop(cur_window_height);
    $('html, body').scrollLeft(cur_window_width);
});
```

Comment: why to use both html and body? can i use only body?

Comment: `body` and `html` for browser compatibility. You may be fine with `body` if working with modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#cur').offset().top,
    scrollLeft: $('#cur').offset().left
}, 'slow');
```

Instead of using:

```
$('#cur').scrollTop(cur_window_height);
$('#cur').scrollLeft(cur_window_width);
```

Comment: `$('#cur').offset()` allows us to retrieve the current position of **cur** element relative to the document. Then we animate the **html & body** to scroll to those positions with a _slow_ effect. I hope you got it @alexela.

Comment: Is there a difference between scrollTop and just top in animate? Like .animate({top+100},'slow') ??

Comment: **scrollTop** is used for the current vertical position of the scroll bar, whereas **top** is used for the top position of element.

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` set the scrollbar position. Your `#curr` doesn't have scrollbars, so instead you could scroll the body:

```
$('body').scrollTop(cur_window_height);
$('body').scrollLeft(cur_window_width);
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWswQ/)